# 64bit AMD catalyst driver

Tags: ati, catalyst

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

IS there a 64 bit AMD catalyst driver for 12.10?  I installed catalyst 12.9 but that borked my graphics and would only allow me to boot into command line mode.